# Angular object arr with splice of object property

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript, object

Have an issue. I have a component with some logic of creating & deleting input fields

.ts

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  resource: Resource[] = [];
  fieldId = 0;
  testArr = ['1', '2', '3', '4'];

  ngOnInit() {
    this.resource = this.getResource();
  }

  addRes(resource: Resource) {
    resource.resourceInputFields = ['', ...resource.resourceInputFields];
    console.log(this.resource);
  }

  removeRes(resource: Resource, index: number) {
    resource.resourceInputFields.splice(index, 1);
  }

  getResource(): Resource[] {
    return [
      {
        resourceLink: 'link',
        resourceInputFields: [],
        resourceId: '',
      },
    ];
  }
}

export interface Resource {
  resourceLink: string;
  resourceId: string;
  resourceInputFields: string[];
}
```

.html

```
<div *ngFor="let res of resource">
  <a>{{ res.resourceLink }}</a>
  <button class="btn" (click)="addRes(res)">+</button>
  <div class="fields">
    <div *ngFor="let resourceField of res.resourceInputFields; index as i">
      {{ i }}
      <input type="text" [ngModel]="resourceField" />
      <button class="btn" (click)="removeRes(res, i)">-</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Trouble is: my splice, working like shift, it deleting last element in arr.

I need, to delete a field, exactly that, where my plus button is. And if there is any value, in input field what I going to delete, I need to remove a value too;
[stackbiz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ploawn?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: The splice operation is working as expected. However, since you are rendering the indices of the array in the html template, it feels like the array is shifting.

If you replace the line inside addRes method to: `resource.resourceInputFields = [`${Math.random()}`, ...resource.resourceInputFields];`
You shall see that the correct elements are getting deleted.

Comment: can u plz show me in my stackbiz, I didn't get

Comment: Check it out: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-u9karw

Comment: Yes, u'r right, it's work fine and delete correct field. So I think, that I should to refactor my addRes method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is only in using "`index as i`" like labels in your input array.
The minus button removes the right input.
You can see it in this modified version, with fixed index labels:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-splice-input-array?file=src/app/app.component.ts

String labels are created on the fly in testArr:

```
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular ' + VERSION.major;
   resource: Resource[] = [];
   resourceValues = [];
  fieldId = 0;
  testArr = [];

  ngOnInit() {
    this.resource = this.getResource();
  }

  addRes(resource: Resource) {
    this.resourceValues.push('');
    if (this.testArr.length) {
      this.testArr.push((+this.testArr[this.testArr.length - 1] + 1).toString());
    } else {
      this.testArr.push(0);
    }
    resource.resourceInputFields = ['', ...resource.resourceInputFields];
  }

  removeRes(resource: Resource, index: number) {
    resource.resourceInputFields.splice(index, 1);
    this.testArr.splice(index, 1);
    this.resourceValues.splice(index, 1);
    // console.log(this.resourceValues);
  }

  getResource(): Resource[] {
    return [
      {
        resourceLink: 'link',
        resourceInputFields: [],
        resourceId: '',
      },
    ];
  }
}
```

And in template use the array, not the index, like label:

```
{{ testArr[i] }}
```

**EDIT:**

For the other question, you missed the two-way data binding.
Instead of `[ngModel]` you have to put `[(ngModel)]` and furthermore you need an editable property on purpose to keep the information of the input value (this.resourceValues in my example).

An example in the updated stackblitz:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-splice-input-array?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Reference:
https://angular.io/guide/forms

Comment: But when I write something in input, and try to delete it, it delete a field but not a value. I can't understand what;s wrong with it. And idk how to fix it. If u know, tell me plz. Try in u'r stackbiz version of my code, write something in input and then delete it, and u'll see a trouble.

Comment: For the other question, you missed the two-way data binding.
Instead of [ngModel] you have to put [(ngModel)] and furthermore you need an editable property on purpose to keep the information of the input value (this.resourceValues in my example).

Answer (score 1):

I've checked your stackbliz..
Your code is absolutely working fine..
For debugging i added a bit of code..
Please check the below one

```
  addRes(resource: Resource) {
    resource.resourceInputFields = [ ""+resource.resourceInputFields.length,...resource.resourceInputFields];
    console.log(resource.resourceInputFields);
  }

  removeRes(resource: Resource, index: number) {
      resource.resourceInputFields.splice(index, 1);
     console.log(resource.resourceInputFields);
  }
```